# Rails 4 - Remove "created_at" and "updated_at" from render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to remove these datas from one resource I do:

```
@teams = Team.all

render json: @teams, :except => [:created_at, :updated_at],
```

My doubt is when I have many includes like these:

```
@teams = Team.all

render json: @teams, :include => [:stadiums, :scores, :links, :rounds]
```

How do I remove from all of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Correction:** You can do something like

```
render json: @teams.to_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at], :include => { :stadiums => { :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]}, ... })
```

<strike>There is no simple way of doing this without iterating over the relevant models, obtaining the attributes hash and selecting the desired attributes.</strike>

Such use cases are often solved elegantly using json templating DSLs like [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

To illustrate this using jbuilder:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.array! @teams do |team|
    json.name team.name
    json.stadiums team.stadiums do |stadium|
      json.name stadium.name
      # Other relevant attributes from stadium
    end
    # Likewise for scores, links, rounds
  end
end
```

Which would produce the output as:

```
[{
  name: "someteamname",
  stadiums: {
    name: "stadiumname"
  },
  ...
}, {...},...]
```

If you find this too verbose for your use case, as @liamneesonsarmsauce has pointed out in the comments another solution is to use [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

Using this approach you can specify a serializer class for each of your models, listing the allowed attributes which would become a part of json response. For example

```
class TeamSerializer  < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name # Whitelisted attributes

  has_many :stadiums
  has_many :scores
  has_many :links
  has_many :rounds
end
```

You can define similar serializers for associated models as well.

Since associations are seamlessly handled in a way that is already familiar to rails developers, unless you require much customization of the generated json response, this is a more succinct approach.

Comment: In addition, instead of jbuilder or rabl, I prefer to use https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers Active Model Serializers.

Comment: The `{ include: { stadiums: { except: :foo } } }` syntax doesn't work for `except`, only stuff like `methods`? I can't test at the moment.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is doable. It would seem I got a bit careless.

Answer (score 3):

How 'bout adding to `models/application_record.rb`

```
# Ignore created_at and updated_at by default in JSONs 
# and when needed add them to :include
def serializable_hash(options={})
  options[:except] ||= []
  options[:except] << :created_at unless (options[:include] == :created_at) || (options[:include].kind_of?(Array) && (options[:include].include? :created_at))
  options[:except] << :updated_at unless (options[:include] == :updated_at) || (options[:include].kind_of?(Array) && (options[:include].include? :updated_at))

  options.delete(:include) if options[:include] == :created_at
  options.delete(:include) if options[:include] == :updated_at
  options[:include] -= [:created_at, :updated_at] if options[:include].kind_of?(Array)

  super(options)
end
```

then use it like

```
render json: @user
# all except timestamps :created_at and :updated_at

render json: @user, include: :created_at
# all except :updated_at

render json: @user, include: [:created_at, :updated_at]
# all attribs

render json: @user, only: [:id, :created_at]
# as mentioned

render json: @user, include: :posts
# hurray, no :created_at and :updated_at in users and in posts inside users

render json: @user, include: { posts: { include: :created_at }}
# only posts have created_at timestamp
```

So in your case, your code remains the same

```
@teams = Team.all
render json: @teams, :include => [:stadiums, :scores, :links, :rounds]
```

and yeah, you get them all without `:created_at` and `:updated_at`. No need to tell *rails* to exclude that in every single model, hence keeping the code **real DRY**.